# How to substitute HTML tag dynamically without losing events

Tags: jquery, html

I've got an html *ul* tag where I have something like this:

```
<div id="sidebar"> 
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <div id="clickable">
                <img src="img/img8.png" alt="Descripción de la igen 8.png">/img>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="clickable">
                <img src="img/img10.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 10"></img>
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

This is a common list, that is showed as a slider. As you can see, each image is inside a div where you can click and show it in another div.

Ok, I have this oter list:

```
<div id="seleccion_galeria">Selecciona la secci&oacute;n que te gustar&iacute;a visualizar:</div>
            <div id="lista_galerias">
                <ul>
                    <li><div id="escaparates_show">Escaparates</div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#escaparates_show').click(function()
                            {
                                console.log('clicked');
                                $('#menu').html('');
                                $('<li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/img8.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 8."></img></div></li><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/img10.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 10"></img></div></li><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/img13.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 13"></img></div></li><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/img15.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 15"></img></div></li><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/img20.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 20"></img></div></li>')
                                    .prependTo('#menu');
                                $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Escaparates');
                            });
                        </script>
                    </li>
                    <li><div id="decoracion_show">Decoraci&oacute;n</div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#decoracion_show').click(function()
                            {
                                console.log('clicked');
                                $('#menu').html('');
                                $('<li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/img8.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 8."></img></div></li><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/img10.png" alt="Descripción de la imagen 10"></img></div></li>')
                                    .prependTo('#menu');
                                $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Decoración');
                            });
                        </script>
                    </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

This is a list that shows the possible images that each element of this last list contains. When I click each element on the list, it erases the html of the first *ul* "#menu" list and substitutes it for the content I wish. With that, I can show diferent lists of images clickable and expandable on another div.

The problem is that, when I substitute the content for the new list, it shows the new list of images perfectly, but it doesn't inherit the **"clickable"** event, so the first time I substitute the HTML tag, it looses it's clickable.

Anyone can have an idea why does this happen?

Thanks!

Edit:

For the same problem, I have this jquery event:

```
$('#menu').on("hover", '#menu li', 
function() {    
//mouse over LI and look for A element for transition
$(this).find('img')
    .animate( { opacity:1 }, 200)
});
```

It works for all the inheritated elements, but I can't make the "mouseleave" event to inherit. If I add:

```
        $('#menu').on("hover", '#menu li', 
    function() {    
        //mouse over LI and look for A element for transition
        $(this).find('img')
            .animate( { opacity:1 }, 200)
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('img')
            .animate( { opacity:0.5 }, 200)
    });
```

It doesn't work. How it works for the hover onleave event??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('.clickable').live('click',function(){
      //do stuff here
    });
OR

$('body').delegate('.clickable','click',function(){
  //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on`, and if you're stuck on an older version of jQuery, use `delegate`.

Comment: I used the $('body').delegate method and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: What about the 'hover' method?? I can't make it inherit both onmouseenter and onmouseleave. I can only put the event onmouseenter. If I try to add the onmouseleave it doesn't work! See edit for more explanations...

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an element from the DOM, any event handlers bound to that element will no longer function. You need to use event delegation to bind the event handler to an ancestor element that will always be in the DOM. You can do this with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$("#menu").on("click", ".clickable", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This will bind the event handler to the parent `ul` element. Since most DOM events bubble up the tree, they can be captured on an ancestor element. When the event reaches the `ul`, the `on` method will check to see if it originated on an element matching the selector. If it did, the event handler will be executed.

This has the added benefit of only having one event handler instead of many (one for each `.clickable` element), which is more efficient.

Comment: I tried yours, sorry but I misunderstood something, but I will try it somewhere else, because I understand what you say, and it looks logical, but it didn't work for me. But I think it's my fault because I don't know hot to use it exactly. But thanks! I will for sure use it in future!

Comment: @Sonhja - No problem :) My version will only work if you're using jQuery version 1.7 or above. For older versions you will have to use `delegate`. I'm glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use the .on method for binding your events, this allows event delegation. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Extract:

"Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers."